# Expect telnet automation fails without interact

Tags: telnet, expect

The following Expect script works, but the `interact` at the end forces the user into an interactive session.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 10
spawn telnet sometelnetserver.com 10000

foreach line [split [read [open somefile.txt r]] "\n"] {
    send "$line\n"
}

interact
```

However, removing the `interact` stops telnet from connecting.  The script outputs

```
spawn telnet sometelnetserver.com 10000
```

and the remote never gets a connection.

**Solution**

Hackily solved by sending a proper quit command before interact so there's nothing to interact with.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn -noecho telnet sometelnetserver 10000

foreach line [split [read [open somefile.txt r]] "\n"] {
    send -- "ed77e768-0a1f-4fda-98c0-c3e5af441f78 $line\r"
}

send \035
send quit\r
interact
```

This seems more than a little sketchy though, because it will still hang if the server doesn't respond.

Comment: Is there any prompt or other visual indication when you are connected? Usually the next thing after `spawn` is `expect`.Also, terminate the commands you send with `\r` instead of `\n`

Comment: Thanks for the help! The expect worked, but now the program only sends SOME lines because it exits before the others are complete. Any ideas on that one?

Comment: Nevermind, for some reason sending a proper quit signal fixed it.  Thanks again! =)